# Python 3: Authenticate using response-kerberos package

Tags: python-3.x, kerberos

I'm trying to authenticate to a server using the requests_kerberos package, following the instructions here:

https://github.com/requests/requests-kerberos

```
import requests
from requests_kerberos import HTTPKerberosAuth

kerberos_auth = HTTPKerberosAuth()
r = requests.get(<myserver>, auth=kerberos_auth)
r.text
```

And here is the response:

'Apache Tomcat/6.0.53 - Error report

## HTTP Status 401 - Authentication required

**type** Status report

**message** Authentication required

**description** This request requires HTTP authentication.

#### Apache Tomcat/6.0.53

'

`klist` shows that I have a valid TGT.

I have tried setting the principal directly, but that didn't help. I can authenticate using curl:

```
curl -i -L --negotiate -u : "<server>"
```

I'm not sure what else to try; everything is happening "behind the scenes" so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I'm not familiar with how Kerberos is configured in Tomcat, but there should be some way to get log info from it. That's where I'd start. Is it receiving a token, and what does it think is wrong? If you can't see what the server is doing, then compare the headers of the curl request to those of your python request. Also check how many requests python is doing. Usually clients send no credentials at first, then get a 401 from the server, then follow up with a new request with the credentials (you can see curl doing this if you turn up verbosity).

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve this? I am facing the same problem and nothing that I have tried seem to work. 
I have used `HTTPKerberosAuth(force_preemptive=True, principal="<username@REALM:password>")` and I managed to get a `requests_kerberos.exceptions.KerberosExchangeError: authGSSClientStep()  failed: ('SSPI: InitializeSecurityContext: The logon attempt failed\r\n',)` instead of the usual 401, but no real progress.

Comment: Same here, I also facing  similar problem